# JSON html string is not being converted to html by innerhtml

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

I am using javascript and php and need to pass some HTML in the JSON variable (PHP->JS).

Unfortunately, due to some environmental constraints I am limited in the jQuery I can use. Using things such as `jQuery.parseJSON(str)` and `$.parseJSON(str)` throw unexpected token errors.

Therefor I need a purely javascript approach to handling html in a JSON variable. Currently, the HTML string is just printed as a string on the page, though I need it to take effect as HTML.

My JS code is as follows:

```
document.getElementById("activeDescription").innerHTML = response['description'];
```

and the results ends up just being text on the HTML page as follows:

```
<p>helloworld</p>
```

whereas I expect just

```
helloword
```

to be displayed on the HTML page. On alert(response['description']) I receive

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;
```

**EDIT**

When I use

```
jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
```

everything is peachy but this code

```
jQuery.parseJSON(response['description']);
```

gives me an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & " error

Comment: what is returned by `response['description']`? It's not clear what you expected to happen.

Comment: unexpected token errors? are you `json_encode`ing your php arrays?

Comment: so to be clear, you just need a pure javascript way of decoding html specific characters?  It sounds like you are getting `&lt;` and `&gt;` in your string

Comment: You have a 0% accepted rate, please accept some answers on your older questions.

Comment: `alert(response['description']);` .. are the characters like `<p>` or `'&gt;p&lt;` ?

Comment: I went back and accepted some of the answers that successfully answered my past questions. My apologies; oft times i'm more of a lurker and that unfortunately persisted even when I was the one asking questions

Comment: You'll need to decode that first (or use json_encode on your server side), thats your problem.

Comment: @Gabriel My apologies for the previous comment sounding snarky. I have removed it since you accepted answers. It is more or less for your benefit. People aren't inclined to help you if you don't provide them with feedback. Anyway glad you got your question answered. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably a encoding problem. You can fix by decoding the characters.

In javascript:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = encoded;
var decoded = div.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

In PHP, look at this link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php